# Using awk, how to convert dates to week and quarter?

Tags: date, awk, date-formatting, week-number, date-manipulation

Using awk, how to convert dates (yyyy-mm-dd) to week and quarter (first day of week set to monday)?

Input:

```
a;2016-04-25;10
b;2016-07-25;20
c;2016-10-25;30
d;2017-02-25;40
```

Wanted output:

```
a;2016-04-25;10;2016-w17;2016-q2
b;2016-07-25;20;2016-w30;2016-q3
c;2016-10-25;30;2016-w43;2016-q4
d;2017-02-25;40;2017-w8;2017-q1
```

Comment: What did you try? I'd use `date` for it (ISO week, Sunday/Monday starting week etc.).

Comment: @JamesBrown while read f1 f2 f3; do echo -n $f1; echo -n " "; echo -n $f2; echo -n " "; date -d $f2 +%V;done < input
.... But not getting the quoting correct.. and not using awk... :p

Comment: @Markus add the code you tried to question instead of comments... and see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 on specifying delimiters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F';' '{ split($2,d,"-"); w = strftime("%W", mktime(d[1]" "d[2]" "d[3]" 00 00 00")); 
           q = int((d[2]+2)/3); 
           print $0,d[1]"-w"w,d[1]"-q"q}' OFS=';' file
```

The output:

```
a;2016-04-25;10;2016-w17;2016-q2
b;2016-07-25;20;2016-w30;2016-q3
c;2016-10-25;30;2016-w43;2016-q4
d;2017-02-25;40;2017-w08;2017-q1
```

---

- `split($2,d,"-")` - split the 2nd field (`date`) by separator `-`
- `mktime(datespec)` - turn *datespec* (date specification) into a timestamp
- `strftime("%W", mktime(d[1]" "d[2]" "d[3]" 00 00 00"))` - format the time returned by `mktime()` function according to `%W` (the week number of the year)
- `q = int((d[2]+2)/3)` - calculating the *quarter* number. The quarter is equivalent to ***3*** months. So we'll use 3 as a divisor.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

Comment: @EdMorton, yes, just missed that from my "vision area"

Comment: This solution do not solve the week going over new year's eve :)