# Using awk, calculate average of rows based on string in 2nd and 5th column and value in 3rd column, and append result

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, average, calculated-columns

This is a variant on [Using awk, how to convert dates to week and quarter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44214899/using-awk-how-to-convert-dates-to-week-and-quarter/44215103?noredirect=1#comment75441575_44215103)

Input data.txt:

```
a;2016-04-25;10;2016-w17;2016-q2
b;2016-04-25;20;2016-w17;2016-q2
c;2016-04-25;30;2016-w17;2016-q2
d;2016-04-26;40;2016-w17;2016-q2
e;2016-07-25;50;2016-w30;2016-q3
f;2016-07-25;60;2016-w30;2016-q3
g;2016-07-25;70;2016-w30;2016-q3
```

Wanted output.txt:

```
a;2016-04-25;10;2016-w17;2016-q2;50
b;2016-04-25;20;2016-w17;2016-q2;50
c;2016-04-25;30;2016-w17;2016-q2;50
d;2016-04-26;40;2016-w17;2016-q2;50
e;2016-07-25;50;2016-w30;2016-q3;180
f;2016-07-25;60;2016-w30;2016-q3;180
g;2016-07-25;70;2016-w30;2016-q3;180
```

Hence, calculate the quarterly average of the days which has data and append the result.

For 2016-q2 the average is calculated as follows:

```
(10+20+30+40)/2 = 50     ("2" is the number_of_unique_dates for that quarter)
```

For 2016-q3 the average is:

```
(50+60+70)/1 = 180
```

Here is my work in progress which seem quite close to a final solution, 
but not sure how to get the "number of unique dates" (column 2) 
and use as divisor?

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR==FNR { s[$5]+=$3; next }
{ print $0,s[$5] / need_num_of_unique_dates_here }
 ' output.txt output.txt
```

Any idea how to get the "number of unique dates" per quarter?

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for pointing this out! Replaced pattern with string.

Comment: I started with the input in my previous question but the question became lengthy so in order to make it compact I selected the data above..

Comment: Yes, I completely agree!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
$5 != p5 { prt(); p5=$5 }
{ lines[++numLines]=$0; dates[$2]; sum+=$3 }
END { prt() }
function prt(   lineNr) {
    for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
        print lines[lineNr], sum/length(dates)
    }
    delete dates
    numLines = sum = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a;2016-04-25;10;2016-w17;2016-q2;50
b;2016-04-25;20;2016-w17;2016-q2;50
c;2016-04-25;30;2016-w17;2016-q2;50
d;2016-04-26;40;2016-w17;2016-q2;50
e;2016-07-25;50;2016-w30;2016-q3;125
f;2016-07-25;60;2016-w30;2016-q3;125
g;2016-07-25;70;2016-w30;2016-q3;125
h;2016-04-01;70;2016-w30;2016-q3;125
```

Answer (score 1):

Another ***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -F';' '{ a[$5][$2]+=$3; r[NR]=$0; q[NR]=$5 }
     END { 
           for (i in a) { s=0; len=length(a[i]); 
               for (j in a[i]) { s += a[i][j] } 
               a[i]["avg"] = s/len 
           } 
           for (n=1;n<=NR;n++) { print r[n],a[q[n]]["avg"] }
     }' OFS=";" file
```

The output:

```
a;2016-04-25;10;2016-w17;2016-q2,50
b;2016-04-25;20;2016-w17;2016-q2,50
c;2016-04-25;30;2016-w17;2016-q2,50
d;2016-04-26;40;2016-w17;2016-q2,50
e;2016-07-25;50;2016-w30;2016-q3,180
f;2016-07-25;60;2016-w30;2016-q3,180
g;2016-07-25;70;2016-w30;2016-q3,180
```

---

- `a[$5][$2]+=$3` - multidimensional array, summing up values for each unique date within a certain *quarter*
- `len=length(a[i])` - determining the number of unique dates within a certain quarter
- `for(j in a[i]){ s+=a[i][j] }` - summing up values for all dates within a quater
- `a[i]["avg"]=s/len` - calculating average value

Comment: Thanks for the solution, for some reason the output order of rows are changed in my output? I use GNU Awk 4.0.1.

Comment: d,e,f,g,a,b,c instead of a,b,c,d,e,f,g. The rows appear correct however.

Comment: @Markus, ok, got it. Fixed

Comment: One small thing the OFS is set to , and could be changed to ;

Comment: @Markus, yes, missed that occasionally, fixed